# The ring of integers of $\mathbf{Q}(p^{1/p})$ for prime $p$

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am completing an exercise for my Algebraic Number Theory class and have so far proved that the ring of integers of $\mathbf{Q}(m^{1/n})$  is contained in $\frac{1}{nm} \mathbf{Z}[m^{1/n}]$. I did this by considering a dual basis of the traceform.

I now want to specialise this result for $n=m=p$ where $p$ is prime and I am unsure how to proceed. Any advice?

Some ideas were to compute the discriminant of $T^p-p$ which is (up to sign) $p^{2p-1}$ so its hard to make any conclusions using this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt[p]{p})$. From the equation
$$
{\rm disc}(\mathbf Z[\sqrt[p]{p}]) = [\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\sqrt[p]{p}]]^2{\rm disc}(\mathcal O_K)
$$
and the left side being ${\rm disc}(T^p - p)$, a power of $p$ up to sign, the index $[\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\sqrt[p]{p}]]$ is a power of $p$.

At the same time, since $T^p - p$ is Eisenstein at $p$ we have $p \nmid [\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\sqrt[p]{p}]]$ by Theorem 2.3 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/totram.pdf) (that property of the ring generated by the root of an Eisenstein polynomial is *very* useful in basic examples).

The index $[\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\sqrt[p]{p}]]$ is a power of $p$ and is not divisible by $p$, so it is $1$. Thus $\mathcal O_K = \mathbf Z[\sqrt[p]{p}]$.

More generally, if $a$ is a squarefree integer other than $\pm 1$ and $n \geq 2$ only has prime factors among the prime factors of $a$, then $T^n - a$ is irreducible and $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[n]{a})$ has ring of integers $\mathbf Z[\sqrt[n]{a}]$: use the same reasoning as above (${\rm disc}(T^n - a) = \pm n^na^{n-1}$, whose only prime factors are prime factors of $a$, and $T^n - a$ is Eisenstein at each prime factor of $a$).

Answer (score 3):

So we know that the ring $O$ of integers of $K=\mathbb{Q}(p^{1/p})$ satisfies $\frac{1}{p^2}\mathbb{Z}[p^{1/p}] \supset O \supset \mathbb{Z}$.

Now, $O$ has a unique prime ideal above $p$, the ideal $\pi=(p^{1/p})$.

Now, for $x=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{a_ip^{i/p}} \in \mathbb{Q}[p^{1/p}]$, it’s easy to see that all the $a_ip^{i/p}$ have distinct $\pi$-valuation, so that $v_{\pi}(x)$ is the minimum of the $pv_p(a_i)+i$ for $0 \leq i < p$.

In particular, if $x \in O$, $v_{\pi}(x) \geq 0$ so $v_p(a_i) \geq 0$ for each $i$. We already know from the above that every $p^2a_i$ is an integer, hence every $a_i$ is an integer, so $O=\mathbb{Z}[p^{1/p}]$.

Comment: I am not familiar with $\pi$ - valuation of $x$ I just want to check is it the highest power of p^1/p that divides $x$. If so if x=p^-1 p^1/p why is $v_{\pi}(x) \geq 0$

Comment: In practice, $v_{\pi}(x)$ is indeed the highest power of $p^{1/p}$ that divides $x$, but that’s not a very good definition. I don’t understand your second question – you seem to have left out a few key signs in $x$, which doesn’t look like it would be in $O$ anyway…

Comment: why is for $x \in O$ is $v_\pi(x) \geq 0$ @Aphelli

Comment: also whats the actual definition then?